# video controlls like pause or volume not working in react-html5video

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, smart-tv

I want to have a video player in my react tv project and I need to customize it, I used react-html5video and it`s working fine but the controls such as pause, fullscreen, video, seeking... none of them works and I get this error for example on pause click:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined
>       at togglePause (bundle.js:29547)
>       at HTMLDivElement.onPlayPauseClick"

Here is my code(its a smarttv app with react) and I'm new to react so sorry if it's silly:

```
import {
    apiHelpers,
    Captions,
    Controls,
    DefaultPlayer as Video,
    Fullscreen,
    Mute,
    Overlay,
    Play,
    PlayPause,
    seek,
    Subtitles,
    Time,
    Volume,
} from 'react-html5video'

class ReactMovie extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { videoEl: '', }
        this.videoitem = this.videoitem.bind(this)
    }

    videoitem(e) {
        const videoelement = e.videoEl
        this.setState({ videoEl: videoelement })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Video videoEl={this.state.videoEl} id="thisvideo"
                   ref={this.videoitem} autoPlay loop muted
                   controls={['PlayPause', 'Seek', 'Time', 'Volume',
                       'Fullscreen', 'Captions']}
                   playsinline={false}
                   poster="/react-tv/image/myimage.jpg"
                   onPlay={() => console.log("playing")}>
                <source src="/react-tv/video/streamer.mp4"
                        type="video/mp4"/>
                <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srcLang="en"
                       src="/react-tv/video/streamer.mp4" default/>
            </Video>
        )
    }
}

ReactTV.render(<ReactMovie/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```